# Missing left join when using bookshelf/knex

Tags: sql, node.js, left-join, bookshelf.js, knex.js

for some reason, in some cases knex doesn't add left join to the query. I tried to reproduce the bug with minimal code, So I tried to use knex with in-memory sqlite3.

```
var knex = require('knex')({
    client:'sqlite3',
    connection: {
    filename: ":memory:"
    },
    debug: true
});

var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

var Conversation = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'conversations',
});

Conversation
    .where(qb => {
        qb
            .leftJoin('conversations_recipients', function () {
                this.on('conversations_recipients.conversationId', 'conversations.id');
            });
    })
    .fetch();
```

When I check the debug messages on the console, I get:

```
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  bindings: [ 1 ],
  sql: 'select "conversations".* from "conversations" limit ?' }
```

And there's the left join is missing. Someone knows what's wrong with this code, and how can I include the desired join?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this syntax correct? `.where(qb => {`

Comment: Yes, it's es6 arrow function. It runs without syntax errors in node v6.

Comment: It's hard to judge from your minimal code example, but wouldn't `Conversation.fetch({ withRelated: 'recipients' })` give you the expected result, assuming _Conversation_ had a `hasMany` association to a new model class _Recipient_?

Comment: @bgerth yes, I know this code is not very practical. I wrote it only to reproduce a problem with minimal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `where` instead of `query`. Also you don't need to use the `join` callback unless you're doing complex join logic. Refer to knex documentation for [`where`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where) and [`join`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-join). And Bookshelf documentation for [`query`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-query)

```
Conversation.query(qb =>
  qb.leftJoin(
    'conversations_recipients',
    'conversations_recipients.conversationId',
    'conversations.id'
  );
).fetch().then(conversations => { // ...
```